# Trouble breaking out of a loop

Tags: ocaml

I'm starting to learn OCaml, and I don't understand why this loops indefinitely:

```
let x = true in
while x do
    print_string "test";
    x = false;
done;;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because OCaml let bindings are immutable. This exact issue is [discussed in detail](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/if_statements_loops_and_recursion.html) in the ocaml.org tutorial. Use a ref instead, and set and get the value it holds using `!` and `:=`:

```
let x = ref true in 
    while !x do
        print_string "test";
        x := false
    done;;
```

Answer (score 4):

One reason to study OCaml is to learn how to compute with immutable values. Here's a version that doesn't depend on a mutable variable:

```
let rec loop x =
    if x then
        begin
        print_string "test";
        loop false
        end
in
loop true
```

The trick is to reimagine the mutable values as function parameters, which allows them to have different values different times.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to run ocaml with warnings and strict sequence on to detect problems. e.g.

```
$ ocaml -strict-sequence -w A
    OCaml version 4.01.0

# let x = true in
  while x do
    print_string "test";
    x = false;
  done;;      
Error: This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type
     unit
```

This shows the problem: `x = false` is testing whether `x` is false or not, not doing an assignment.